# Too many values to unpack? python-radar

Tags: python, pandas, api

I have problem which when i run the code it shows an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\server\PycharmProjects\Publictest2\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    Distance = radar.route.distance(Starts, End, modes='transit')
  File "C:\Users\server\PycharmProjects\Publictest2\venv\lib\site-packages\radar\endpoints.py", line 612, in distance
    (origin_lat, origin_lng) = origin
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

My Code:

```
from radar import RadarClient

import pandas as pd

API_key = 'API'

radar = RadarClient(API_key)

file = pd.read_excel('files')

file['AntGeo'] = Sourced[['Ant_lat', 'Ant_long']].apply(','.join, axis=1)

file['BaseGeo'] = Sourced[['Base_lat', 'Base_long']].apply(','.join, axis=1)

antpoint = file['AntGeo']

basepoint = file['BaseGeo']

for antpoint in antpoint:

    dist= radar.route.distance(antpoint , basepoint, modes='transit')

    dist= dist['routes'][0]['distance']

    dist= dist / 1000
```

Comment: The error traceback does not match the code provided

Comment: In addition to mismatch between your err traceback (as pointed out by @buran) and your sample code, it is difficult understanding what your problem is. Kindly show us what your dataset looks like. Read more about radar-python.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your error code does not match your given code sample correctly.

It is apparent you are working with the python library for the Radar API.
Your corresponding line 19 is `dist= radar.route.distance(antpoint , basepoint, modes='transit')`

From the `radar-python` ['pypi manual'](https://pypi.org/project/radar-python/), your route should be referenced as:

```
## Routing
radar.route.distance(origin=[lat,lng], destination=[lat,lng], modes='car', units='metric')
```

Without having sight of your dataset, `file`, one can nonetheless deduce or expect the following:

1. Your `antpoint` and `basepoint` must be a two-item list (or tuple).
   For instance, your `antpoint` ought to have a coordinate like `[40.7041029, -73.98706]`
   See the [radar-python manual](https://radar-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2. line 11 and 13 in your code
   `file['AntGeo'] = Sourced[['Ant_lat', 'Ant_long']].apply(','.join, axis=1)`

   `file['BaseGeo'] = Sourced[['Base_lat', 'Base_long']].apply(','.join, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occuring at this part:

```
Distance = radar.route.distance(Starts, End, modes='transit')
(origin_lat, origin_lng) = origin
```

First of all check the amount of variables that "origin" delivers to you, it's mismatched with the expectation I guess.

Comment: This is more of a comment that an answer. Also, the line `(origin_lat, origin_lng) = origin` appears in the library code, not in the code that OP wrote.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).